# Fundamental Backbone issue with registering event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js

I really don't understand how Backbone is supposed to handle common scenarios where you want to register event handlers on HTML before the HTML is inserted into the DOM.

Most Backbone views look like so:

```
var PortalView = Backbone.View.extend({


        events: {

            'click #logout-li-id': 'onClickLogout'   //1 (doesn't work)
        },

        initialize: function (opts) {


            var self = this;

            $('#logout-li-id').on('click', function (event) { //2 (doesn't work because '#logout-li-id' is not in the DOM yet
               event.preventDefault();
               alert(event);
            });

        },

        render: function () {

            var self = this;

            var template = allTemplates['templates/portalTemplate.ejs'];

            var ret = EJS.render(template, {});

            $('#main-div-id').html(ret);

            $('#logout-li-id').on('click', function (event) { //3 works!
                event.preventDefault();
               alert(event);
            });

            return this;

        },
        onClickLogout: function(event){
           alert(event);
         }
    });
```

As you can see above, I have labeled the 3 similar calls to register an event handler on the DOM element '#logout-li-id' - the problem is that the only successful call to register the callback on the DOM element is in the render function (call #3), which occurs *after* the el for this Backbone view is inserted in the DOM. So, the standard way of declaring a key in the events object for the Backbone view doesn't work! So what is the right way to do this with Backbone?

Answer (score 3):

Backbone expects that events a view will handle via the `events` hash are children of the view's `el` (that is, the root DOM element of the view). It looks like you are probably not attaching this view to the parent of the DOM element you're listening to - is `$('#main-div-id')` a child of the view's `el`?

The standard approach here would be something like:

```
var PortalView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // Associate this view with the element it will manage
    el: '#main-div-id',

    events: {
        'click #logout-li-id': 'onClickLogout'
    },

    render: function () {
        var template = allTemplates['templates/portalTemplate.ejs'];
        var ret = EJS.render(template, {});
        // Render to this view's element
        this.$el.html(ret);
    }
});
```

More detail: The `events` hash works by adding delegated event handlers to the view's DOM node. Essentially, every click within the view's DOM tree will call a handler that checks whether the event target matches a given selector. If so, it passes the event to the view method you specify. But this only works if the element you click is in the view's DOM tree - otherwise, the view's DOM will never get the event and the event handler will never be called.

Comment: thanks, I wonder if I can call something like "this.delegateEvents( )" in the bottom of the render function? I just need a Backbone function that registers the events *after* I render the template to the DOM.

Comment: in theory, calling this.delegateEvents( ) would achieve the behavior I want, but I am not sure in reality that it does, because Backbone kinda sucks

Comment: It doesn't need to be registered after it's added to the DOM - the delegated events are handled by the view's `el`, and can be registered regardless of whether it's in the DOM or not. If you're trying to bind to something outside the view's `el`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Yeah I dont think what I am doing is that wrong. The element that I want to attach a listener to is in the template for this particular view, in this case, portalTemplate.ejs. This is normal. I think Backbone might be expecting a template property on the view, instead of a template being resolved in the render function.

Comment: in other words, logout-li-id is in the html of portalTemplate.ejs

Comment: so backbone simply  doesnt handle this scenario as is

Comment: Backbone expects the view to be associated with a single DOM element, which may or may not exist in the current DOM - if not provided, it will make one for you. How you handle templates or what elements you modify in `render` aren't relevant here - the events are only going to work within the context of the view's `el`. While you might not be "wrong", rendering to something outside the `el` is not what Backbone expects you to do.

Comment: thanks for the info. my scenario seems like a common scenario, I will post an answer to the question if I discover something